# EFI GPT Windows 7 boot-loader/manager issue and grub

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, multi-boot, gpt, efi

My computer(asus N76VM 64 bit) with windows 7 (64 bit home professional) pre-installed got in a bad state while partitioning from a later installed Ubuntu environment. This had lead me to run `testdisk` and copy every seperate partition onto a backup HDD.
I managed to get it al back onto the original hard drive in a state that resembles the state before things went bad.

****I was able to boot into both operating systems before all the hassle started!****

Since "repairing" the HDD the computer still doesn't want to start windows 7. It's got `Grub 1.99` installed and (hoping this would help me) `rEFInd` but they both don't work. I must note that `Grub` **does** display entries for both Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Ubuntu starts like it should, but when I choose for Windows the screen tells me: Invalid EFI filepath.

Another step I tried was running a Windows 7 repair cd, enter command prompt, reassign drive letters (they were C:\ for [OS] and D:\ for [DATA]) so they fitted the original state and then the following commands:
`Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`
`Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`
`Bootrec.exe /ScanOs`
`Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`
Rebooted
But they did not help, so I tried the following:
`bootsect /nt60 c: /force /mbr`
`bcdboot c:\windows /s c:`
Again, no sigar. So I started looking further and ran into [this website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnb4T.png) which gave advice I am a bit concerned about trying, for I don't know the possible outcomes and I don't want to be loosing anything all over again.

Running `boot info script` gives me the following output (the order of the partitions might seem weird, I know that, but I don't think it is of any concern:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1880670208 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,gpt2)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda1 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda1 starts at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/refind/refind_x64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda2 
                       and looks at sector 1569963600 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       for (,gpt2)/boot/grub on this drive.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /NST/menu.lst /bootmgr /Boot/BCD 
                       /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       194,559       192,512 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2   1,556,162,560 1,864,286,207   308,123,648 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3   1,233,352,704 1,556,162,559   322,809,856 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4         194,560 1,233,352,703 1,233,158,144 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5   1,880,690,688 1,936,979,967    56,289,280 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda6   1,864,286,208 1,880,670,207    16,384,000 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda7   1,880,670,208 1,880,690,687        20,480 BIOS Boot partition

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        E138-2A7D                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331   ext4       
/dev/sda3        4DFF26211F14E609                       ntfs       DATA
/dev/sda4        4A814AE3556AE075                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda5        1B1666970F6A4336                       ntfs       Recovery
/dev/sda6        03dc7be8-7682-4219-8ab0-ae5d09caa1b1   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw)
/dev/sda2        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-35-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-35-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-35-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-29-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-18-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-18-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-18-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic root=UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,gpt4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4A814AE3556AE075
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda5)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1B1666970F6A4336
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
 menuentry "Windows 7" {
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod ntfs
     set root='(hd0,msdos4)'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4A814AE3556AE075
     chainloader +1
  }
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs optional,nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=598ab3d1-e1aa-4041-ba78-1de8c6762331 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=E138-2A7D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=03dc7be8-7682-4219-8ab0-ae5d09caa1b1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/sda7 none swap sw,noauto 0 0
#UUID=E138-2A7D /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
#UUID=E138-2A7D /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
UUID=E138-2A7D  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 814.208938599 = 874.250190848  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 765.658302307 = 822.119342080  boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic               1
 743.588668823 = 798.422253568  boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic               2
 769.143566132 = 825.861615616  boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic               1
 765.462841034 = 821.909467136  boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic                  2
 742.506031036 = 797.259780096  boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic                  2
 769.006057739 = 825.713967104  boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic                  1
 765.658302307 = 822.119342080  initrd.img                                     1
 765.658302307 = 822.119342080  initrd.img.old                                 1
 765.462841034 = 821.909467136  vmlinuz                                        2
 765.462841034 = 821.909467136  vmlinuz.old                                    2

============================== sda4/NST/menu.lst: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NeoSmart NeoGrub Bootloader Configuration File
#
# This is the NeoGrub configuration file, and should be located at C:\NST\menu.lst
# Please see the EasyBCD Documentation for information on how to create/modify entries:
# http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda4: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             NST/menu.lst                                   0

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
```

Boot flag removed from the EXT4 partition. Now the next step is to get the windows partition that needs to be booted at C:\ instead of the EXT4 partition. I tried a couple of times with 'diskpart' on a windows live cd recovery environment within 'cmd'. However, at each reboot the drive letters get reassigned.

***My setup from before everything went haywire***

[image]

Edit:

Replaced the bootmgfw.efi file with a copy from the original OS partition. Now when booting windows 7 from rEFInd I get the following screen:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:  

1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.  
2. Choose your language settings, and click "Next."  
3. Click "Repair your computer."  

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.  

File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD  

Status: 0xc000000f  

Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
```

EDIT 19 feb '14

---

I found on the site of Microsoft a Windows 8.1 trial iso. Downloaded it, installed in virtual machine 64-bit. Copied the iso to the virtual disk and used some instructions I found for making the USB recognized on the VM. Then with other instructions I found the way of making it EUFI boot able and it worked.

Now I'm waiting for the repair to be done. It's taking half an hour now and I don't know when it will be done. For the sake of reference I will be adding the sources of the information when/if this operation will be done

Comment: I cannot recommend wrining an MBR to a GPT drive. You can manage boot entries like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325048/cleaning-up-and-changing-the-efi-boot-order-permanently-using-eifbootmgr
Use GRUB only for starting Ubuntu. You can (should be able to) switch between them by selecting the right boot device at startup.

Comment: Thank you, but would I not also be able to do that through the BIOS setup menu? If so, then this won't work for me. May I be so bold to ask you to upvote my question, so I can post pictures in my question for clarification?

Comment: assumee there is no windows bootloader. I have to get it at the right place manually

Comment: A note, your Boot Info Script gives a misleading order of partitions as per disk. It's actually `/dev/sda`{1,4,3,2,6,7,5}.
Of course, your partition numbering has also changed through all of this: please upload updated versions of image and boot info script output

Comment: @MilindR http://pastebin.com/cm6gfCyG the new script output

Comment: @MilindR I updated my post. Also I used the commands you suggested in the windows repair disk cmd environment and applied my drive letters where necessary. unfortunately the '/f UEFI' parameter was unrecognized by `bcdboot` so I tried it with leaving that part out. It did not change anything noticibly

Comment: Ok I will try with `/f ALL` allthough the option `/f` doesn't seem to exist in my version. Maybe it will work. I will post a screenshot of what happens.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the differences between BIOS-mode (aka CSM or legacy-mode) booting and EFI-mode (aka UEFI-mode) booting. Windows ties these boot modes quite closely to the partition table type: Windows will boot in BIOS mode if and only if the disk uses the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table type, and in EFI mode if and only if the disk uses the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table type. Your question title implies you're using GPT, but it's not clear that your computer *originally* used GPT. (Most Windows 7 systems used BIOS and MBR, although some Windows 7 systems sold in late 2011 and later used EFI and GPT.) If your original installation used BIOS/MBR, you'll need to install an EFI-mode Windows boot loader. This process is described [here.](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI)

If your computer originally used EFI/GPT, you may also need to re-install the boot loader; or it could be that you've overlooked some critical detail, such as a proper re-creation of the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which holds EFI boot loaders.

If you need more help, try running the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) in Linux. This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to a pastebin site and post the URL for the file here. That will give us more precise and detailed information about your current configuration, which may help in fixing it.

---

***EDIT:***

Your Boot Info Script output indicates that you don't have a Windows boot loader installed on your computer. You'll have to fix that to get Windows booting. In particular, because the disk uses GPT, you must install an *EFI* boot loader for Windows. Most pages that describe Windows boot repair assume a BIOS-based system, and so will be 100% useless to you. [This page](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) describes how to convert Windows from a BIOS-mode boot to EFI-mode boot, so something along those lines might work. There may be other pages that will help, too; or you can post on a Windows forum for help.

One more point, which you might want to deal with before trying to install a Windows boot loader: Your `/dev/sda2` uses an ext4 filesystem, but is marked as being an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) This is incorrect and could cause problems down the line, so you should fix it. There are a number of ways to do this, depending on what partitioning software you use. For instance, in [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), you should change the type code from EF00 to 8300 by using the `t` option, then write the changes via the `w` option. In `parted` or GParted, you'd remove the "boot flag" (and in GParted apply the changes).

Comment: Thank you Rod, I will read what you have suggested. In the meantime I updated my post to give the output of `boot info script`

Comment: See the above edit.

Comment: Rod, when I am in rEFInd and choose for the windows option, I receive the following message: "starting bootmgfw.efi" "invalid loader file" "Error: Not Found while loading bootmgfw.efi" It feels like I'm getting closer all the time, it's getting frustrating.

Comment: Those messages sound like you've now got a file with the name of the Windows boot loader (`bootmgfw.efi`), but that it's damaged. You might try running `dosfsck` on the ESP in Linux, and if that fails, re-install the Windows boot loader again.

Comment: That didn't do anything. I looked through some old pictures of my setup though and I noticed I had a seperate partition with the flag bios_grub. To me this suggests that originally was a MBR disk, or am I wrong? What if I removed all the bootmanagers that are currently installed, including GRUB and rEFInd, would I then be able to change the disk to MBR, fix windows bootmanager and reïnstall GRUB (or something simmilar)? Or does the bios_grub partition imply nothing according to bios boot or EFI?

Comment: The `bios_grub` partition type exists *only* on GPT disks, so its presence does *not* imply that the system was originally a BIOS/MBR installation, although you might once have had Linux installed in a BIOS/GPT configuration. Have you actually replaced the `bootmgfw.efi` file with a known-good copy, either from another computer or by running a Windows recovery tool? If so, then something strange is going on. If not, please replace that file.

Comment: Rod, I did as you suggested,  replaced the bootmgfw.efi file. Output is in the edit of my post.

Comment: See [this article](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) and try following steps 3.6 and on (or maybe even 3.5 and on).

Comment: You need to see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/405759/cant-boot-into-windows-7-efi-gpt-after-recovery-operation) to get more context.

Comment: @RodSmith I have gotten from 3.5 to this point: "3.5.3 Restart the system with the Windows x64 Setup disc. Enable UEFI boot mode in the BIOS" so this will be my next step.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks a lot. I tried everything you suggested but I still get the same error message. I can't seem to get the cd to boot from UEFI mode. I don't know what to try anymore! Any suggestions?

Comment: I am going to try with a windows 8 trial cd. I have read that it starts in UEFI more easily and it has the same tools als windows 7 repair disk

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks to everyones help and some searching I have managed to solve the problem. I am typing this from the Windows 7 environment (which boots nicely with rEFInd by the way)

Comment: +1 for Boot Info Script, helped point out a number of errors in my setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try grabbing a GPARTED liveCD and setting your windows partition to have the 'boot' flag. this will probably supersede your GRUB installation but at least you'll have a point to work from.

Comment: If I could just upload a picture.. May I be so bold to ask you to upvote my question so I can post pictures?

Comment: That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, please follow Rod Smith instructions on changing the type of the EXT4 partition to not be an ESP, if you have not already done so.

Next, I suggest that you rewrite your protective MBR with one from `gdisk`. `Bootmgr` does not seem to like changes to the disk signature made by `grub` to the MBR.

Essentially, run `gdisk /dev/sda`, then:

- `x`
- `n`; confirm... this will not affect any EFI bootloaders.
- `w`

If this doesn't work...

Also, booting into the Windows install disc will indeed reassign letters each time. No need to worry. Internally, each drive and partition is identified by a unique GUID (on top of the GPT GUIDs, usual Microsoft style to maintain consistency with MBR systems).

Let's regenerate an appropriate BCD

- Use diskpart to identify the drive letters assigned to the EFI System
  Partition(`/dev/sda1` : call it S:) and the Windows Boot partition (`/dev/sda3` :
  call it C:)
- If the ESP does not have a drive letter, assign one using
  `mountvol s: /s`
- `bcdboot C:\windows /s S: /f ALL`

Comment: In gdisk, after pressing 'w' to write I get the following output `Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): ` Are you sure this is not harmfull for my data?

Comment: Yes, I have done this before, as long as you're sure you only used `n` which rewrites the protective MBR, and you don't have any BIOS booting operating systems, it's safe.

Comment: Yes, I've managed the flag and changed it like Rod said. I just entered the commands in gdisk and will reboot now to check how it worked.

Comment: My bad... `/f` does not exist in the Windows 7 version of `bcdboot`.

Comment: I am looking for alternatives...

Comment: Thank you, I created a pastebin script, please take a look and tell me if you find a simmilar command http://pastebin.com/Zv6eGfwu <-- this represents the output of `bcdboot C:\windows /s S: /f ALL`

Comment: Did you boot the DVD specifically in UEFI mode?

Comment: No, I don't know how to achieve that. There is an option for `pcx oprom` in BIOS that changes something in legacy/uefi, but it is not specified what it does. The only time I get a boot option for UEFI DVD is when I want to boot in Ubuntu live DVD. This gives me 2 DVD options: `UEFI DVD` and `PS slimtype`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13038/discussion-between-milind-r-and-nkciy84)

Comment: To answer your question from chat, I haven't realy gotten anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

If disk style is GPT then Windows 7 (only 64-bit version) can boot only using UEFI boot.

To repair Windows 7 booting:

1) using some disk management tool ensure you have a EFI System partition (usual size is 100 MB in FAT32 format) and a Microsoft Reserved (128 MB) partition.

EFI System partition is where boot files are placed. You can use "diskpart" on recovery console to check partitions:

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MTNB

DISKPART> sel disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     I                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     D   TEMP         NTFS   Partition     50 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      RAW    Partition     18 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     E   DATA         NTFS   Partition    100 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     F   W8           NTFS   Partition     80 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     C   W7           NTFS   Partition     80 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 6     G   VHD          NTFS   Partition     60 GB  Healthy
  Volume 7     H   W81          NTFS   Partition     60 GB  Healthy
  Volume 8     J   W81_src      NTFS   Partition   5368 MB  Healthy
  Volume 9     R   Recovery     NTFS   Partition    300 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 10        EFI SYSTEM   FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
```

**You must ensure also there is a 128 MB Microsoft Reserved Partition on disk !**

```
DISKPART> lis par

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Recovery           300 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System             100 MB   301 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved           128 MB   401 MB
  Partition 4    Primary             50 GB   529 MB
  Partition 5    Primary             18 GB    60 GB
  Partition 6    Unknown           2048 MB    78 GB
  Partition 7    Primary            100 GB    80 GB
  Partition 8    Primary             80 GB   180 GB
  Partition 9    Primary             80 GB   260 GB
  Partition 10   Primary             60 GB   340 GB
  Partition 11   Primary             60 GB   400 GB
  Partition 12   Primary           5368 MB   460 GB
```

Here Partition 3 is Microsoft Reserved partition.

If you don't have a Recovery partition in the beginning of disk EFI System partition should be first, followed by 128 MB Microsoft Reserved partition.

2) **mountvol s: /s** (mounts EFI System partition to drive letter s:)

3) Using bcdboot from recovery CD/USB:

**bcdboot Y:\windows /s s:** 
where Y: is Windows 7 drive.

There are NO BOOT SECTORS involved during EFI boot (no MBR, no PBR/VBR) but you could rewrite MBR using "bootsect":

**bootsect /nt60 ALL /force /mbr**

[Link to Microsoft where you can see how to use diskpart for creating UEFI partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825686.aspx).

[Repair Windows BCD with explanations for UEFI.](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would one go and create such a 128 MB microsoft Reserved Partition from Linux? Or should I use the Windows repair cd? If so, how would I get it there? I have enoug unallocated space to make one, after the FAT32 boot partition.

Comment: I would follow the Link to Microsoft - how to use diskpart for creating UEFI partitions given above. I am not 100% but gparted should also be able to create MSFT RESERVED - its a flag like "boot" in gparted for partition properties.

Comment: Thank you. I have after moving some partitions around I got myself a 'msftres' labled partition. It's hard to figure out what type of filesystem should be applyed to it. It's now set to be NTFS but I'm not sure, as I read some hints towards making it some kind of FAT, and then I am not even sure if it should be FAT16, FAT32 and so on...

Comment: MSFT Reserved is a special partition and has a special GUID which identifies it as such - no need for formatting (you should not be able to format it at least in Windows).